# SpringData Repository Error

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have problem with SpringData and JPA. When I add methods to HomeRepository interface, I get an error. I'm using jparepository interface and in a pom.xml file there is a MySQL database set. Those are just my beginnings with spring so I need some help of someone who knows their stuff.Here are my codes and logs:

Class User:

```
package com.kampusbaza.kampusbaza.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name= "User")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Long iduser;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL")
    private String name;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL")
    private String surname;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL")
    private String email;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL")
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String surname, String email, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getIduser() {
        return iduser;
    }

    public void setIduser(Long iduser) {
        this.iduser = iduser;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User[" +
                "id=" + iduser +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", email=" + email +
                ", password=" + password +
                ']';
    }
}
```

HomeRepository:

```
package com.kampusbaza.kampusbaza.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface HomeRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends 
JpaRepository<T, ID> {
void delete(T deleted);
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
List<T> findAll();
}
```

UserRepository:

```
 package com.kampusbaza.kampusbaza.repository;


import com.kampusbaza.kampusbaza.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.io.Serializable;
public interface UserRepository extends HomeRepository<User, Long>  {
}
```

Log:

> 2017-10-30 18:34:19.298  INFO 9076 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2017-10-30 18:34:19.454  INFO 9076 --- [           main]
>   utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : Error starting
>   ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run
>   your application with 'debug' enabled. 2017-10-30 18:34:19.486 ERROR
>   9076 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               :
>   Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]:
>   Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'homeRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>   ~ [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapabl
>   eBeanFactory.java:1173)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactor
>   y.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>   :513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
>   83) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-
>   4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~ [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-
>   4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-
>   4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:76)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:86
>   7) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-
>   4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~ [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-
>   1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] at
>   com.kampusbaza.kampusbaza.KampusbazaApplication.main(KampusbazaApplication.java:20)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]:
>   Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'homeRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>   ~ [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>   ~ [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] ... 18 common
>   frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]:
>   Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'homeRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>   ~ [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapabl
>   eBeanFactory.java:1173)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactor
>   y.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>   :513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
>   83) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-
>   4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~ [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-
>   4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-
>   4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] atorg.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(Configurati
>   onClassEnhancer.java:389)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java
>   :361) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6618329a.mvc
>   ConversionService()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcConfigura
>   tionSupport.java:560)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer
>   (WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:432)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupp
>   ort.java:520) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcA
>   utoConfiguration.java:384)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6618329a.CGL
>   IB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$1()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6618329a$$Fa
>   stClassBySpringCGLIB$$bc1685e3.invoke()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java
>   :358) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6618329a.req
>   uestMappingHandlerAdapter()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_141] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_141] at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_141] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_141] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>   ~ [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] ... 19 common
>   frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]:
>   Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'homeRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>   ~ [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>   ~ [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] ... 44 common
>   frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'homeRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class java.lang.Object
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
>   va:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>   :555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
>   83) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-
>   4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~ [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-
>   4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-
>   4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084)
>   ~[spring-context-
>   4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:95)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-
>   1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na] at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:88)
>   ~[spring- data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.(Repositories.java:81)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-
>   1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na] at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter.setApplicationContext(DomainClassConverter.java:98)
>   ~[spring- data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration.addFormatters(SpringDataWebConfiguration.java:95)
>   ~[spring-data- commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addFormatters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:80)
>   ~ [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addFormatters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:
>   77) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcConversionService(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java
>   :588) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6618329a.CGL
>   IB$mvcConversionService$32()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6618329a$$Fa
>   stClassBySpringCGLIB$$bc1685e3.invoke()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java
>   :358) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6618329a.mvc
>   ConversionService()
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_141] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_141] at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_141] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_141] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>   ~ [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] ... 45 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class java.lang.Object at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-
>   5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final] at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70)
>   ~ [spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
>   atorg.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java
>   :68) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:153)
>   ~ [spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:100)
>   ~ [spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:82)
>   ~[spring- data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199)
>   ~ [spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
>   atorg.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277
>   ) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
>   atorg.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.jav
>   a:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
>   ~ [spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
>   .java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
>   va:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE] ... 70
>   common frames omitted Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What's the purpose of `HomeRepository`? You're just redeclaring methods. It looks like you're trying to inject a generic repository into something (that you didn't show), but Spring needs to know the actual type so that it can generate the appropriate JPA queries, etc. (And you shouldn't include `password` in `toString()`!)

Comment: Did you add `@EnableJpaRepositories` to your configuration class? You should also annotate your services with `@Service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HomeRepository` serves no purpose. The methods you are defining already exist in the interface `JpaRepository` so just make your `UserRepository` extend that instead:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>  {
}
```

This should fix your issues.

Comment: Long does implement Serializable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html and before Spring Data 2.0.0 it was required for ID classes to extend serializable.

Comment: Oh whoops. I am totally blind. I did not see Serializable when I checked it earlier. It just seemed strange to me for the ID to be required to be Serializable. It makes sense that the persistent entity should be though. Thanks for correcting me. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It was a leftover from the very begining when Hibernate had that exact requirement.